# Do i need to use a mail helper class to setup a sendgrid gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email

I have created a contact us form in my ruby on rails website. The final stage is to allow messages posted on the form to be forwarded to my email address. For this I have installed the sendgrid gem. However there is one final step and I am stuck. I am following the ruby instructions here

[enter link description here][1]https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sendgrid#ruby

To understand what to do i need to know 2 things:

1. Do I use the code for with mail helper or without mail helper (I don't know what a mail helper is)?
2. where do I put this code in my rails app?

Any other information about installing sendgrid would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I recently just set up a contact section on my website using Sendgrid. It works like a charm and I didn't need to install any gems. Here are the steps to take to get your mailer working in production, assuming you already set it up correctly and tested it in your development environment.

First if you haven't already, you need to add a credit card to your Heroku account. This is just for verification and so that you can use add-ons.

In your terminal run:

```
 $ heroku addons:create sendgrid:starter
```

Fix the ActionMailer settings to work with Sendgrid by adding this to your production rb file:

```
Rails.application.configure do

      ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
        :address        => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
        :port           => '587',
        :authentication => :plain,
        :user_name      => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
        :password       => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
        :domain         => 'heroku.com',
        :enable_starttls_auto => true
        }

      # more code here
    end
```

You don't need to worry about ENV variables because Heroku automatically adds those from the heroku addons:create command from earlier.

Comment: This is the best way I find also, no need for the gem really.

Comment: i have tried this and i see that now my message is saving in the command line in local host so looks promising solution. the only thing now is that my " git push heroku master" fails when i try to push to heroku. push to github however works fine. (as an aside: what is the differnce between using this code and installing the gemfile?)

Comment: It may be failing because you have:
[config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings]
in your development rb file.
Comment these lines out and replace with:
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test

Comment: @ Russell Kranz. I dont see either of these lines in development.rb. should i add it?

Comment: You should have had those when tested mail locally. Are you sure the mailer was working properly before attempting to set it up with Sendgrid? As in you were able to send and receive an email in your inbox? It's important to do that when using a Mailer. Its hard to figure out your problem without more information. Go to your Heroku account and then your app and hit the Settings tab > Reveal Config Vars. Look if it has the SENDGRID_PASSWORD and SENDGRID_USERNAME listed. If not, then you are not running the add on correctly.

Comment: $ heroku logs
might be able to help you spot the error if that doesn't help.